# Unexpected value in PostgreSQL foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I have two tables, `profiles` and `cities` and I want to add a column `city_id` to `profiles` table as a foreign key and make it reference `id` column in `cities` table. So I run the following code:

```
alter table profiles add column city_id integer REFERENCES cities(id);
```

The strange thing is that when I look at the `profiles` table DDL I see the following:

```
FOREIGN KEY ("30") REFERENCES public.cities (id)
MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

when I expected it to be

```
FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES public.cities (id)
MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *How* do you "look at the DDL" and what's your version of Postgres? And are you sure you are looking in the same DB and schema?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think I have found the problem, thanks to you :) I think it's a bug in the new JetBrain's DataGrip IDE ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be a bug in the new JetBrains' DataGrip IDE because when I use `pgAdmin` I see what I expected:

```
CONSTRAINT profiles_city_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
REFERENCES cities (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you use "copy DDL" from context menu.
Try this: — Press Ctrl+q (Ctrl+j on Mac) on the table, OR — Double click on the object and then choose DDL tab (instead of "Data")